# How can I import a json file from my desktop to my notebook?

Tags: import, jupyter-notebook, geojson

I have a geojson file located on my desktop that I would like to import/read into Jupyter. Not sure how to do it though.

I'm using a Mac. I've tried a with open statement, but that didn't seem to work, unless it's supposed to and I just got the file path wrong. Any ideas?

**Code below:**

```
path="/Users/myname/Desktop/chicago.geojson"

with open(path) as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

print (data)
```

Comment: Have you check whether you got the file path wrong or not?

Comment: The error I get is "No such file or directory...." My filepath is: /Users/myname/Desktop/chicago.geojson       the code is above

Comment: Have you check whether the file exist and that path?

Comment: The file is located on my desktop, if that's what you're asking? I even copied it into my browser and the path (url) was the same.

Comment: Could it be because I'm loading a geojson file as a json file (see code)?

Comment: No, loading geojson and json is fine. It's probably a problem with your Python working directory

Comment: Took the easy way out and just loaded the file into the notebook directory.

Comment: Yea, nothing wrong with your code. It's just the Python working directory configuration